# List Category and Sub Category Of Product Purchased Separately on WooCommerce Order Page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I require category and subcategory of product purchased in WooCommerce to be echoed separately as data attributes on WooCommerce Order page. Following $terms returns me list of categories and sub categories both for the product purchase.

Is there any way to list main category and sub category separately for the product purchase via WooCommerce

```
// Display order items product categories and its id 
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 'display_custom_data_in_emails', 10, 4 );
function display_custom_data_in_emails( $item_id, $item, $order, $bool ) {
    // Get the product categories for this item
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $item->get_product_id(), 'product_cat', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );
    $term_ids = wp_get_post_terms( $item->get_product_id(), 'product_cat', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
    echo "<div data-category=" . implode(', ', $terms) . "></div>";
    echo "<div data-catid=" . implode(', ', $term_ids) . "></div>";
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get all terms that are related to that product. Then you can iterate the loop of terms and check `parent == 0` so you will get only parent terms. Try the below code.

```
// Display order items product categories and its id 
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 'display_custom_data_in_emails', 10, 4 );
function display_custom_data_in_emails( $item_id, $item, $order, $bool ) {
    // Get the product categories for this item
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $item->get_product_id(), 'product_cat' );

    $parent_categories = $child_categories = $parent_categories_ids = $child_categories_ids = array();

    foreach( $terms as $category ) {
        if( $category->parent == 0 ) {
            $parent_categories[] = $category->name;
            $parent_categories_ids[] = $category->term_id;
        }else{
            $child_categories[] = $category->name;
            $child_categories_ids[] = $category->term_id;
        }
    }

    echo '<div data-category="'.implode(', ', $parent_categories).'">Parent category names: '.implode(', ', $parent_categories).'</div>';
    echo '<div data-catid="'.implode(', ', $parent_categories_ids).'">Child category names: '.implode(', ', $parent_categories_ids).'</div>';    

    echo '<div data-category="'.implode(', ', $child_categories).'">Parent category ids: '.implode(', ', $child_categories).'</div>';
    echo '<div data-catid="'.implode(', ', $child_categories_ids).'">Child category ids: '.implode(', ', $child_categories_ids).'</div>';    
}
```

**Tested and works**
[image]

Comment: it works just code you have mapped child category name to parent category ids and parent category id to child categories.  I have changed in my code. Thanks